Zombie movie wherein a man discovers an unfamiliar word
A friend told me about this a while back. The movie was supposedly named The Young Tree or something similar.

A guy is reading a children's book in a library and comes across an unfamiliar word. He proceeds to look it up in a dictionary. Everyone in the library then starts to stare at him.
In the street, people start staring at the man, too. It turns out that they are all zombies, and he is (one of) the last human(s) left.
The movie ends with the man failing to outrun his assailants and being initiated as a zombie.

I'd expect it to be an early 2000s movie in the English language, but who knows?
